# ¿Cómo mover elemento después de tres etiquetas jQuery?

Tags: jquery

En algunos artículos los párrafos están entre `div > p` dado a que según los estilos que se den al texto o el tipo de formato, desde el `WYSIWYG HTML` Editor puede generarlo de tal manera:

```
<div id="destination">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
</diV>
```

Entonces es imposible que vaya el texto en un solo orden dado al `WYSIWYG HTML` Editor.

Entonces cuando yo desee mover una información solo va ha funcionar en ciertos contendidos donde se hayan generado todo en una etiqueta o contenedor principal, por ejemplo probé con `div` aplicando la regla `$('#destination>div')` pero esta generado todo el `HTML` en `p` por lo tanto no funcionara:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#source').insertAfter($('#destination>div').eq(3));
});
```

```css
#source {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#destination {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source">
  <p>Source</p>
</div>

<div id="destination">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <pLorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

A diferencia si esta en la condición correcta `$('#destination>p')` ahí si funciona:

```js
 $(function(){
    $('#source').insertAfter($('#destination>p').eq(3));
 });
```

```css
#source {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#destination {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source">
  <p>Source</p>
</div>

<div id="destination">
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
  <p>Destination</p>
</div>
```

Entonces como puedo hacer para que sin importar que etiquetas existan o no dentro del contenedor global `<div id="destination"></div>` dicho contenido se agregue al después de tres etiquetas `.eq(3)` sin importar que sean o no las mimas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si he entendido bien, quieres mover `source` al tercer hijo de `detination` independientemente de quien sea. Entonces, sólo tienes que alcanzar el hijo sin especificar de qué tipo sea: `children(':eq(2)')`, así alcanzará al tercero, sea éste un `p`, un `div`, un `span`....

Por ejemplo:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#source').insertAfter($('#destination').children(':eq(2)'));
});
```

```css
#source {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#destination {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source">
  <p>Source</p>
</div>

<div id="destination">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

Aquí otros dos ejemplos, con un `span` y con un `div`:

```js
$(function(){
  $('#after-five').insertAfter($('#destination').children(':eq(4)'));
  $('#source').insertAfter($('#destination').children(':eq(2)'));

});
```

```css
.green {
  color: white;
  background: green;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}

#destination {
  color: white;
  background: red;
  padding: 4px 8px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="source" class="green">
  <p>Source</p>
</div>
<div id="after-five"  class="green">
  <p>Voy después del 5º</p>
</div>

<div id="destination">
  <p>1. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>2. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <span>3. Yo soy un span que dice: "Lorem ipsum dolor"</span>
  <p>4. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <div>5. Soy el 5º y soy un div</div>
  <p>6. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>7. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>8. Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactamente como lo deseaba gracias :)